# `Expectation` and `NExpectation` producing different results

Tags: numerical-integration, distributions

I'm looking the the integration problem below, and `NExpectation` produces signficantly different results from `Expectation`

```
n = 2;
hs = Table[1/i, {i, 1, n}];
xs = Array[x, n];
dist = MultinormalDistribution[IdentityMatrix[n]];
ratio = TransformedDistribution[Dot[hs^3, xs^2]/Dot[hs^2, xs^2], 
   xs \[Distributed] dist];
Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] ratio]
NExpectation[x, x \[Distributed] ratio, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

This produces

```
5/6
2.4590305666396202347
```

Any idea what's going on there?

Comment: Weird, calculating the expectation by hand gives the correct value `pdf=PDF[ratio,x]; NIntegrate[x pdf,{x,1/2,1}]`

Comment: Try with `NExpectation[x, x \[Distributed] ratio, Method ->"NIntegrate"]`

Comment: Without `WorkingPrecision -> 20`, `NExpectation` gives the correct answer.

Comment: Or if retaining `WorkingPrecision` use `NExpectation[x, x \[Distributed] ratio, WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
 Method -> {"NIntegrate", {MinRecursion -> 15, MaxRecursion -> 20}}]`